# Odd argument in threading.py

Tags: python, multithreading

I found an odd argument of **init** of threading.Thread class.

```
def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs=None, *, daemon=None):
```

What is the seventh argument?
I have never seen such arguments.
Moreover the argument is not used in the `__init__`.
Is it really necessary?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/23038767/3001761, which adds more on *why* this gets used

Comment: I'm sorry for duplication. Thank you.

Comment: Don't worry about it; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates