# Why can default and non-default arguments be mixed freely after *?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a function parameter list, a parameter without a default cannot occur after a parameter with a default,

```
def func(a, b=2, c, d=4, e): .... ERROR
```

unless this is after `*`:

```
def func(a, b=2, *, c, d=4, e): .... OK
```

Why are non-default arguments permitted after default arguments after `*`?

Comment: Have you read [PEP-3102](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)? This covers the *"'single star' syntax for indicating the end of positional parameters"*.

Comment: [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967/python-bare-asterisk-in-function-argument)

Comment: I know that paremeters after `*` are just keyword-only arguments. The doubt is not about that. The question is: Why allowing a mixture of default and no default after * and not before *?

Comment: So where is the confusion? In the first, there is no way of passing `e` without passing `b`, `c` and `d` first (as it's positional). With the second you're forced to name them all. so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Because arguments without default values prior to a single `*` are positional arguments, whereas those after are keyword-only-no-default. Please just read the PEP, it explains the rationale for introducing the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func(2, 2, 2, 2)
```

What would that mean in the context of your first example?