# Python method argument named * (just the asterisk symbol, just one char long)

Tags: python, django

I was looking for something in `Djangos` source code when I came upon the definition of [`django.forms.fields.Field.__init__()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/forms/fields/#Field):

```
class Field:
    def __init__(self, *, required=True, ...):
```

The method has more arguments, but I was surprised by the second argument, which is only the asterisk symbol. I had not seen this before. I could not find an explanation with a few quick google searches.

It is not a valid argument name, meaning I cannot use the passed value in `print(*)`. It is also different from the `*args` and `**kwargs` arguments (I know how to use these 2).

Any explanations for this? Or any links where I can read about this usage?

Comment: It prohibits any positional arguments to be passed in

Comment: Thanks; [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39284225/9225671) (of which this question has been marked as duplicate) has answered my question.