# python: What does / and * mean in the python documentation?

Tags: python-3.x

```
help(sorted)
```

`sorted(iterable, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)`

What can I pass to / and * for example and how would it be useful?

Comment: Can you link the docs you're looking at?  I'm looking at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted but that doesn't match what you have provided.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967/bare-asterisk-in-function-arguments