# invalid syntax with shutil library

Tags: python-3.x

I want to try using this shutil.copy and my files got some symbolic characters inside its name, so I need to use this shutil.copy(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True) command. but the compiler keeps giving me the invalid syntax messages. I had google and didn't find any solution yet for this. anyone can point out what is wrong with my syntax? because I already tried to print out the files inside those directories and it is okay, the network shared folder also got the permission and so on. but don't know what is wrong with my syntax. help me. thanks

This is my current script

[image]

and here is the output I got

File "C:\Users\1000266946\Desktop\sa\we.py", line 17

```
shutil.copy( files, parse_destination_path, * , follow_symlinks = True)
                                              ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.3s]

Comment: Remove the `, *` in your call.

Comment: if i remove that, it will give me this

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1000266946\Desktop\sa\we.py", line 17, in <module>
    shutil.copy( files, parse_destination_path, follow_symlinks = True)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\shutil.py", line 248, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2019-11-05.db'
[Finished in 0.4s]

Comment: oh ya sorry. btw, actually i just started learning python like 2 or 3 days ago hehe

Comment: general comment: please paste the actual code, not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first of all:** the asterisk as you show it can be used in function definitions to define keyword-only arguments (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967/bare-asterisk-in-function-arguments)) - but you don't use it in a function call. So in `shutil.copy(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True)` [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html), it tells you that `follow_symlinks` can only be used as a keyword argument, not as a positional argument.

**second:** take a look at the return value of `os.listdir()`. it returns only file names, without the path as noted in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html). `shutil.copy()` however expects a full path, not only the filename. so what you could do is

```py
for file in parse_source_file_list:
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(parse_source_path, file), os.path.join(parse_destination_path, file))
```

**further reading:** you might also be interested in having a look at `glob` and `pathlib` for file handling purposes (docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib)).

Comment: ohh like that ya, thanks for pointing out my mistakes and also thanks for the guidance u provided, now i know that i misunderstood how does it works before. those documentation really help me. later i will go thru the glob and pathlib also. :D