# What do * (single star) and / (slash) do as independent parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameter-passing, function-parameter

In the following function definition, what do the ***** and **/** account for?

```
def func(self, param1, param2, /, param3, *, param4, param5):
     print(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5)
```

*NOTE: Not to mistake with the single|double asterisks in *args | **kwargs ([solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters))*

Comment: `/` is for [positional-only arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/), while `*` is for [keyword-only arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).

Comment: Please refer to this: [Python Positional-Only Parameters](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/#syntax-and-semantics)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The [function parameter syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters)(`/`) is to indicate that some function parameters must be specified positionally and cannot be used as keyword arguments.(***This is new in `Python 3.8`***)

Documentation specifies some of the use cases/benefits of [positional-only parameters](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/)

> 1. It allows pure Python functions to fully emulate behaviors of
>    existing `C` coded functions. For example, the built-in `pow()`
>    function does not accept keyword arguments:
>
>    ```
>    def pow(x, y, z=None, /):
>        "Emulate the built in pow() function"
>        r = x ** y
>        return r if z is None else r%z
>    ```
> 2. Another use case is to preclude keyword arguments when the parameter
>    name is not helpful. For example, the builtin `len()` function has
>    the signature `len(obj, /)`. This precludes awkward calls such as:
>
>    ```
>    len(obj='hello')  # The "obj" keyword argument impairs readability
>    ```
> 3. A further benefit of marking a parameter as positional-only is that
>    it allows the parameter name to be changed in the future without
>    risk of breaking client code. For example, in the statistics module,
>    the parameter name dist may be changed in the future. This was made
>    possible with the following function specification:
>
>    ```
>    def quantiles(dist, /, *, n=4, method='exclusive')
>        ...
>    ```

Where as `*` is used to force the [caller to use named arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14302007/6699447). Django documentation [contains a section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/releases/2.0/#form-fields-no-longer-accept-optional-arguments-as-positional-arguments) which clearly explains a  usecase of named arguments.

> **Form fields no longer accept optional arguments as positional
> arguments**
>
> To help prevent runtime errors due to incorrect ordering of
> form field arguments, optional arguments of built-in form fields are
> no longer accepted as positional arguments. For example:
>
> `forms.IntegerField(25, 10)`
>
> raises an exception and should be replaced
> with:
>
> `forms.IntegerField(max_value=25, min_value=10)`

Suppose we have a method called `func`:

```
def func(self, param1, param2, /, param3, *, param4, param5):
     print(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5)
```

It must called with

```
obj.func(10, 20, 30, param4=50, param5=60)
```

OR

```
obj.func(10, 20, param3=30, param4=50, param5=60)
```

ie,

1. `param1`, `param2` must be specified [positionally](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument).
2. `param3` can be called either with [positional](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument) or [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument) argument.
3. `param4` and `param5` must be called with [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument) argument.

DEMO:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def func(self, param1, param2, /, param3, *, param4, param5):
...         return param1, param2, param3, param4, param5
...
>>> obj = MyClass()
>>>
>>> assert obj.func(10, 20, 30, param4=40, param5=50), obj.func(
...     10, 20, param3=30, param4=40, param5=50
... )
```

Comment: Nice; do you have any idea what the point is? Why restrict user freedom like this?

Comment: @Charanor See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/#rationale for the reasons considered by the people who designed and implemented this feature.  Whether you find these to be convincing reasons is up to you; I can argue either way, personally.

Comment: Does the `/` operator only apply to the left parameters? Your descriptions don't seem to make that clear to me, but I might be reading it wrong.

Comment: @GammaGames: Yes.  The order of arguments is always positional-only `/` positional-or-keyword `*` keyword-only.

Comment: another form of dan04's comment: `/` have no effect on arguments listed right to it, and `*` have no effect on arguments listed left to it.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters), the slash is for positional-only arguments, as the docs says:

> There is a new function parameter syntax `/` to indicate that some function parameters must be specified positionally and cannot be used as keyword arguments. This is the same notation shown by `help()` for C functions annotated with Larry Hastings’ [Argument Clinic](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/clinic.html) tool.

And for the asterisk, it's mentioned here in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> For a parameter with a default value, the corresponding argument may be omitted from a call, in which case the parameter’s default value is substituted. If a parameter has a default value, all following parameters up until the “`*`” must also have a default value — this is a syntactic restriction that is not expressed by the grammar.

---

```
def func(self, param1, param2, /, param3, *, param4, param5):
     print(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5)
```

So the ways to call this would be:

```
obj.func(10, 20, 30, param4=50, param5=60)
```

And:

```
obj.func(10, 20, param3=30, param4=50, param5=60)
```