Official Python documentation of os.symlink() function is lacking crucial information
This is the header for the section on the os.symlink() function in official python 3.12 documentation, which is the version of python I am running:
os.symlink(src, dst, target_is_directory=False, *, dir_fd=None)


Create a symbolic link pointing to src named dst.
On Windows, a symlink represents either a file or a directory, and
does not morph to the target dynamically. If the target is present,
the type of the symlink will be created to match. Otherwise, the
symlink will be created as a directory if target_is_directory is True
or a file symlink (the default) otherwise. On non-Windows platforms,
target_is_directory is ignored.

No description is given for the fourth parameter (*) or for the fifth parameter(dir_fd).
I assume the fifth parameter means the directory in which to place the symlink, but I'm not sure I'm right.  I totally missed the fourth parameter when I was writing my code, and now that I see it, I have no idea what to put there, and the docs don't tell me.
This was my code, I know it's wrong, but I don't know what to put for the fourth parameter:
os.symlink(absold, newfn, False, dir)

However, the error message I got was not particularly helpful given that the doc mentions 4 if not 5 parameters.
TypeError: symlink() takes at most 3 positional arguments (4 given)

How do I code this so that the symlink is created in the directory I want it to be?
I am not running from the directory where these files are.
Are the official docs incorrect?

The 4th parameter is just a placeholder and not considered to be a parameter which denotes that everything after it is supposed to be keyword only. docs. If dir_fd is not None, it is used to resolve the relative paths instead of current working directory.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/14301967/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/59661042/3001761

While the question I linked as a duplicate is asking about a different call in particular, the general "what is dir_fd / what does it do?" part isn't call-specific -- it has the same meaning in all syscalls that support it, and thus all higher-level wrappers for those calls.

The * in function definition in python separates position and keyword-only arguments. You can't do os.symlink(a, b, c, d), you have to os.symlink(a, b, c, dir_fd=d). It's a normal python syntax. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions :

Parameters after “*” or “*identifier” are keyword-only parameters and may only be passed by keyword arguments. Parameters before “/” are positional-only parameters and may only be passed by positional arguments.

As for dir_fd, it is a file descriptor refering to directory, a way to reference directories by a number on linux. See https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/os.html#dir-fd .

thank you.  I figuted it out myself, However the symlink created is not openable by the software that wants to open it.
