# Star * in function signature?

Tags: python

I was reading about the `math.isclose` module in python ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose)), and I understood most of it except for one thing.

What does the `*` mean in `math.isclose(a, b, *, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0)`?

Comment: That means those parameters need to have their names included when you use them: `math.isclose(1, 2, rel_tol=0)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bare asterisk in function arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967/bare-asterisk-in-function-arguments)