# Proper way to subclass from sklearn with * argument

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to subclass from `sklearn.svm.LinearSVC` and noticed the `*` argument in the signature. I'm not sure if this `*` refers to **kwargs or *args or something else. I am trying subclass the init function as follows. In this scenario I'm have added a single additional argument `new_string_in_subclass` the init function.
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

```
class LinearSVCSub(LinearSVC):
    def __init__(self, penalty='l2', loss='squared_hinge', *, dual=True, tol=0.0001, C=1.0, multi_class='ovr',
                 fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1, class_weight=None, verbose=0, random_state=None,
                 max_iter=1000, sampler: new_string_in_subclass=None):

        super(LinearSVCSub, self).__init__(penalty=penalty, loss=loss, *, dual=dual, tol=tol,
                                            C=C, multi_class=multi_class, fit_intercept=fit_intercept,
                                                  intercept_scaling=intercept_scaling, class_weight=class_weight,
                                                  verbose=verbose, random_state=random_state, max_iter=max_iter)

        self.new_string_in_subclass = new_string_in_subclass
```

If I want to maintain the functionality of the `LinearSVC` class's other methods, do I need to pass the * argument to the super class's `__init__` function? If so how do I do this? Right now I get a `SyntaxError` as below:

super(LinearSVCSub, self).**init**(penalty=penalty, loss=loss, *, dual=dual, tol=tol,
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: This `*` syntax is for keyword-only arguments. It was added in Python 3.8. See [Positional-only parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters) in the release notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `*` only goes in the definition of a method, not in calls to that method.  The `*` indicates that all parameters after it can only be supplied by name, not by position.  Just leave it out when calling the `super`, and you should be fine.

Comment: I've posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64430351/11542679) about another problem I ran into after this was sorted out. Appreciate if you could have a look. It's about using the above setup with sklearn `GridSearchCV `

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk serves to separate keyword-only parameters: [Bare asterisk in function arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14301967/10495893)  You should skip it when instantiating the sklearn class.