# What does the asterisk * mean as the first argument in the signature of a function/class/method?

Tags: python, signature

I am currently trying to understand the [Tensorforce](https://tensorforce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library . I keep stumbling across a signature in the form:

```
class tensorforce.core.layers.Dense(*, size, bias=True, activation='tanh', dropout=0.0, initialization_scale=1.0, vars_trainable=True, l2_regularization=None, name=None, input_spec=None)
```

[Tensorforce Dense Layer](https://tensorforce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/layers.html)

What does it mean if the asterisk * is at the very beginning and how can I instantiate such a class, or can you do that at all?

An instantiation in the form

```
from tensorforce.core.layers import Dense
d = Dense(4)
```

fails with the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-df27ca99113e>", line 1, in <module>
    Dense(4)

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: This is a more accurate dupe target for this question: [Bare asterisk in function arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14301967/6045800). Any hammerer please edit the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any arguments specified after the `*` "argument" (so in this case, all of them) are [keyword-only arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/). They can only be supplied by keyword, rather than positionally; this means your example should be:

```
from tensorforce.core.layers import Dense
d = Dense(size=4)
```

---

That error message you got is not terribly intuitive, is it? This is a consequence of the fact that in Python, an object's method is essentially a function that [automatically receives the object itself as the first argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self) (which is why you normally write `self` in a method *definition*, but don't supply it when *calling* the method).

In this case, the `__init__` method takes one and exactly one positional argument: its own object instance. Since you also provided `size` positionally, Python complains that it got two arguments—even though you only explicitly gave it one.