# What does an asterisk (*) mean on its own in a function's parameter list?

Tags: python

I've sometimes seen functions in `help(...)` defined like this:

```py
def foo(x, *, y):
    ...
```

What does the lonely asterisk `, *,` in this function definition mean?

Searching for this answer online leads to lots of explanations of this other construction, which doesn't seem to me to be related:

```py
def bar(x, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

A very similar thing is [covered in the Python FAQs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-does-the-slash-in-the-parameter-list-of-a-function-mean) to describe a slash used like this:

```py
>>> help(divmod)
Help on built-in function divmod in module builtins:

divmod(x, y, /)
    Return the tuple (x//y, x%y).  Invariant: div*y + mod == x.
```

So why is this related-seeming syntax with an asterisk not mentioned there? Where is it documented?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967/bare-asterisk-in-function-arguments

Comment: The `/` is a much later (Python 3.8) addition to Python syntax than the `*` (Python 3.0). Both are documented in [Section 8.7](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) of the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html).