# Discord Python Bot : Error when using function to call other function that have * arg parameter

Tags: function, discord, discord.py, bots

So im trying to make a function that call other function like this

```
@command.command()
async def test1(self, ctx):
    text = "hi john"
    await test2(ctx, text)

@command.command()
async def test2(self, ctx, *, text):
    await ctx.send(text)
```

it will say

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: test2() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

and if i tried

```
@command.command()
async def test1(self, ctx):
    text = "hi john"
    await test2(text)

@command.command()
async def test2(self, ctx, *, text):
    await ctx.send(text)
```

it will say

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: test11() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'num'

And if i remove the * from test2 so that it become

```
@command.command()
async def test1(self, ctx):
    text = "hi john"
    await test2(ctx, text)

@command.command()
async def test2(self, ctx, text):
    await ctx.send(text)
```

then it will work perfectly fine.

Note: i need * arg on test2 so that when i type test2, it can receive input more than 1 word. But the problem appears when i use other function to call test2. Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bare asterisk in function arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967/bare-asterisk-in-function-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `invoke()` method.

```py
@command.command()
async def test1(self, ctx):
    text = "hi john"
    await ctx.invoke(self.bot.get_command('test2'), text=text)

@command.command()
async def test2(self, ctx, *, text):
    await ctx.send(text)
```

For the first parameter of `invoke()`, you specify which command you want to call, and all subsequent parameters are used to specify the arguments of that command.