# get_user() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twurl

I've been having issues getting passed this bug, I was wondering If anyone could help. Or could point me in the right direction? I believe the issue may be with API.get_user. But I just cannot find a workaround it.

This script is supposed to read a csv file of Twitter usernames(list.csv) and pull the unique IDs. Then format those IDs into another csv file.(ids.csv)

here is the error I receive when running get_user_ids.py
these lines end up populating in my newly generated ids.csv file.

`get_user() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

```
import tweepy
import time
import csv
import sys


consumer_key = "CONSUMER_KEY"
consumer_secret = "CONSUMER_SECRET"
access_token = "ACCESS_TOKEN"
access_token_secret = "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


def get_user_ids():
    handles = []
    with open("list.csv", "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in reader:
            for elem in row:
                handles.extend(elem.strip().split(','))

        for handle in handles:
            try:
                u = api.get_user(handle[1:-1])
                time.sleep(6)
                print (u._json['id'])
                sys.stderr.write(str(u._json['id']) + "\n")
            except Exception as e:
                print (e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_user_ids()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the *full* traceback of the error.

Comment: what does this "handle[1:-1]" return when you print it?

Comment: @DanielOdicho it prints the Twitter usernames that are stored in list.csv. But removes the first and last letter.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs the error I posted only shows in the generated ids.csv file. I don't get any errors within the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown [in the documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.get_user):

```
API.get_user(*, user_id, screen_name, include_entities)
```

This means that there are no positional parameters; `user_id` and `screen_name` are [keyword-only parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967), so the argument must explicitly name the correct keyword:

```
api.get_user(user_id=handle[1:-1])
```

or

```
api.get_user(screen_name=handle[1:-1])
```

Choose the correct one *according to how `handle[1:-1]` should be interpreted*:

> `user_id` – Specifies the ID of the user. Helpful for disambiguating when a valid user ID is also a valid screen name.

> `screen_name` – Specifies the screen name of the user. Helpful for disambiguating when a valid screen name is also a user ID.