# Python __init__ function in Class

Tags: python, oop

I am starting to build a library for some custom machine learning that I do on a regular basis. I wanted to use scikit-learn as an example of how to structure my code as this is my first time working with classes. Looking at the class for LogisticRegression there is an init function which I believe instantiates the initial state of a LogisticRegression object. All of the items getting initiated appear to be default parameters. However there is a * between penalty and dual which I do not understand. Any help would be appreciated.

The line is 1097 in https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2a2772a87b6c772dc3b8292bcffb990ce27515a8/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py#L783

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bare asterisk in function parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967/bare-asterisk-in-function-parameters)