# Meaning of `*` in function definition before other arguments

Tags: python, function

I have stumbled upon several functions where they are defined as such :

`f(x,y, *, z, w, **kwargs)`

I was wondering what is the purpose of the asterix `*` in the middle ?

Is it used to explicitly separate the arguments `x`, `y` and the others ?
I'm a bit confused on why to put this because we could also remove it like `f(x,y, z, w, **kwargs)` and would change the behavior of `f` ?

Comment: `*` is for *varargs* and `**` is *kwargs*.

Comment: [Asterix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix) is a comic-book indomitable Gaulish warrior.

Comment: [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#special-parameters) covers this.

Comment: Duplicate question where the answer is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967/bare-asterisk-in-function-parameters