# TypeError: StringMethods.rsplit() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use `Series.str.rsplit` to return everything up to the delimiter, but can't seem to get past this TypeError I'm receiving:

```
TypeError: StringMethods.rsplit() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I am using `pandas 2.0.3`. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['tom ent', 'nick', 'krish std', 'jack whatever'],
                    'age': ['5', '6', '7', '8']})

df1['name'] = df1['name'].str.rsplit(' ', 1).str[0]
```

Output should look like:

```
name    age
tom       5
nick      6
krish     7
jack      8
```

Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: I don't get an error with the code you provided. What version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: Wow, you guys should definitely update Pandas then :) This change was not even introduced with the 2.x branch that made everyone complain about the breaking changes.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - Thank you. Just did. [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas) is still on 1.5.3 (which gave a Warning but not an error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Pandas 1.4 and before, the `.rsplit` method [used ordinary parameters](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html), so a call like this would mean that `' '` is the delimiter and `1` is the maximum number of times to split - just like the built-in method of the `str` class.

However, [starting in 1.5](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html), `n` and `expand` are [keyword-only parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967). To use them, the name needs to be specified explicitly, like: `.rsplit(' ', n=1)`.

The idea is that, because the programmer is forced to use names, there is no chance of mistaking the order.