# What is `\*` in Python function definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know what a single asterisk (`*`) means in a function definition. See, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967/what-does-a-bare-asterisk-do-in-a-parameter-list-what-are-keyword-only-parame).

However, the [documentation of `warnings.warn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#available-functions) contains the entry `\*`. What does this symbol combination mean in a function definition?

Comment: You can see in the source code that the function def for `warn` is spread over two lines, with a line break before `*`. The documentation tool seems to have turned that line break into a backslash. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0536bbb192c5ecca5e21385f82b0ac86f2e7e34c/Lib/warnings.py#L297

Comment: I think that's probably a mistake in the doc generation somewhere, you can see from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0536bbb192c5ecca5e21385f82b0ac86f2e7e34c/Lib/warnings.py#L297-L298 it's just `*` to make the last arg keyword-only (and a backslash in that position has no meaning I'm aware of).

Comment: a typos ?? up to 3.11 it's not there https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/warnings.html#available-functions

Comment: I just submitted this as a documentation issue on the python github: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/114811

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typo, up to 3.11 it's not there [warnings.warn(message, category=None, stacklevel=1, source=None)](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn):

```
warnings.warn(message, category=None, stacklevel=1, source=None)

    Issue a warning, or maybe ignore it or raise an exception. The category argument, if given, must be a warning category class; it defaults to UserWarning. Alternatively, message can be a Warning instance, in which case category will be ignored and message.__class__ will be used. In this case, the message text will be str(message). This function raises an exception if the particular warning issued is changed into an error by the warnings filter. The stacklevel argument can be used by wrapper functions written in Python, like this:

    def deprecation(message):
        warnings.warn(message, DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)

    This makes the warning refer to deprecation()’s caller, rather than to the source of deprecation() itself (since the latter would defeat the purpose of the warning message).

    source, if supplied, is the destroyed object which emitted a ResourceWarning.

    Changed in version 3.6: Added source parameter.
```

Try it:

```
def func(\*):

    pass
```

Result:

```
ERROR!
File "<string>", line 1
    def func(\*):
              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

and :

```
def func(po = 4):

    print('po = ' , po)
    pass

a = func( 3)

a = func(po = 3)


def func(*, po = 4):
    
    print('po = ' , po)
    pass

a = func(po = 3)

a = func(3)
```

output :

```
ERROR!
po =  3
po =  3
po =  3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
TypeError: func() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
>
```

See [What does a bare asterisk do in a parameter list? What are "keyword-only" parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967/what-does-a-bare-asterisk-do-in-a-parameter-list-what-are-keyword-only-parame) for explanation :

> Bare * is used to force the caller to use named arguments

and [PEP 570](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/) :

[image]

Comment: Well, it's not just that the typo is not there up to Python 3.11, but the `*` is not there at all.

Comment: More precisely, the typo appeared when Python 3.12 added the first keyword-only parameter to `warnings.warn`.

Comment: @chepner, I am not following,  you mean added `skip_file_prefixes ` the last keyword arg ??

Comment: Yes,  neither `skip_file_prefixes` nor any other keyword-only parameter existed prior to Python 3.12, so there was no reason to include `*` in the signature until then.

Comment: hi thanks , I am getting it now, pep 570 helped me understand / and * in function parameters , https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/