# More arguments in derived class __init__ than base class __init__

Tags: python, inheritance

How can I extend the `__init__` of a base class, **add more arguments to be parsed**, without requiring `super().__init__(foo, bar)` in every derived class?

```python
class Ipsum:
    """ A base ipsum instance. """

    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = flonk(foo)
        grungole(self, bar)
        self._baz = make_the_baz()


class LoremIpsum(Ipsum):
    """ A more refined ipsum that also lorems. """

    def __init__(self, foo, bar, dolor, sit, amet):
        super().__init__(foo, bar)
        farnark(sit, self, amet)
        self.wibble(dolor)
```

The purpose of the example is to show that there is significant processing happening in the `Ipsum.__init__`, so it should not be duplicated in every sub-class; and the `LoremIpsum.__init__` needs the `foo` and `bar` parameters processed exactly the same as `Ipsum`, but also has its own special parameters.

It also shows that, if `Ipsum` needs to be modified to accept a different signature, *every derived class* also needs to change not only its signature, but how it calls the superclass `__init__`. That's unacceptably fragile.

Instead, I'd like to do something like:

```python
class Ipsum:
    """ A base ipsum instance. """

    def __init__(self, foo, bar, **kwargs):
        self.foo = flonk(foo)
        grungole(self, bar)
        self._baz = make_the_baz()

        self.parse_init_kwargs(kwargs)

    def parse_init_kwargs(self, kwargs):
        """ Parse the remaining kwargs to `__init__`. """
        pass


class LoremIpsum(Ipsum):
    """ A more refined ipsum that also lorems. """

    def parse_init_kwargs(self, kwargs):
        (dolor, sit, amet) = (kwargs['dolor'], kwargs['sit'], kwargs['amet'])
        farnark(sit, self, amet)
        self.wibble(dolor)
```

That has the big advantage that `LoremIpsum` need *only* do the parts that are special to that class; handling `Ipsum` arguments is handled by that class's `__init__` without any extra code.

The disadvantage is obvious, though: this is effectively re-implementing the handling of named parameters by passing a dictionary around. It avoids a lot of repetition, but isn't very clear.

What tools are available to avoid the sub-class definitions *always* needing to declare the `foo` and `bar` parameters, and *always* needing to call `super().__init__(foo, bar)`? Those are easy to get wrong, so it would be better if they weren't needed and could **just automatically happen**, while still allowing `LoremIpsum`'s customisation of the initialisation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A flexible approach is to have every method in the ancestor tree cooperatively designed to accept keyword arguments and a keyword-arguments dictionary, to remove any arguments that it needs, and to forward the remaining arguments using `**kwds`, eventually leaving the dictionary empty for the final call in the chain.

Each level strips-off the keyword arguments that it needs so that the final empty dict can be sent to a method that expects no arguments at all (for example, object.__init__ expects zero arguments):

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, shapename, **kwds):
        self.shapename = shapename
        super().__init__(**kwds)        

class ColoredShape(Shape):
    def __init__(self, color, **kwds):
        self.color = color
        super().__init__(**kwds)

cs = ColoredShape(color='red', shapename='circle')
```

For more on this approach, see the "Practical Advice" section of the [Super Considered Super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) blogpost, or see the related at [Pycon video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo).

In your example, the code would look like this:

```
class Ipsum:
    """ A base ipsum instance. """

    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = flonk(foo)
        grungole(self, bar)
        self._baz = make_the_baz()

class LoremIpsum(Ipsum):
    """ A more refined ipsum that also lorems. """

    def __init__(self, dolor, sit, amet, **kwds):
        super().__init__(**kwds)
        farnark(sit, self, amet)
        self.wibble(dolor)
```

An instantiation would look like this:

```
li = LoremIpsum(dolor=1, sit=2, amet=3, foo=4, bar=5)
```

Note, this lets you achieve your original objective of adding new arguments to either __init__ method without affecting the other.

Comment: One downside with this that I see: someone inspecting the signature of the `LoremIpsum.__init__` method doesn't see the important `foo` and `bar` parameters mentioned there. Yet, mentioning them in every derived class is also problematic. That's why I'm hoping for a way that means I don't need to re-implement `__init__` in every derived class.

Comment: If using Python 3 only (and not 2.x), I would suggest forcing the use of kwargs - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14298976/5766144

Comment: It's now over 7 years later and @bignose's comment above is still an issue in Python IDEs. No argument hints are inferred. This answer would be perfect otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

The usual way to write these is roughly as follows:

```
class Ipsum:  # 3.x-ism; in 2.x always inherit from object.
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        # etc...

class LoremIpsum(Ipsum):
    def __init__(self, arg4, arg5, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # 3.x-ism; in 2.x super() needs arguments.
        # Do stuff with arg4 and arg5
```

This does not require modifying derived classes when the base class changes signatures.  You will still need to modify everything that directly instantiates your base class, so changing the signature is still not something you want to do frequently.

This approach is also superior because it will generally behave more or less correctly in the case of multiple inheritance, even if your derived class gets put in front of another derived class in the method resolution order and you've never heard of that other class (in other words, even if `super().__init__()` is calling a method you know nothing about).  This is discussed in detail in Hettinger's [super() considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) blog post.

Comment: Probably passing `*args` here is not a good idea, the arguments can change causing lots of confusion. Should use kwargs instead.

Answer (score 0):

Derived classes need to call the superclass `__init__`.  That's how object-oriented programming works.  Is it brittle?  Yes, it can be; that's why deep or broad class hierarchies aren't usually a good idea.  If the operations on `foo` and `bar` in `Lorem` are significant (as you say they are), then correctly invoking `Lorem.__init__()` is a cost that must be paid.
Default values for `foo` and `bar` (and any new parameters) are the only tool I can think of that might make change the amount of textual change needed, but default values aren't always appropriate, so that mitigation might not apply.

Comment: This doesn't address the question. Yes, `__init__` should, if implemented, call the superclass's `__init__`. But Python allows a derived class to not implement that method, if the superclass's `__init__` is enough. The question is asking how to avoid *implementing* an `__init__` at all in the derived class.

Comment: You said "while still allowing `LoremIpsum`'s customisation of the initialisation.", which sounds to me like something that belongs in an `__init__` method.  Your `parse_init` is a nonstandard function doing a standard job, which seems confusing and error-prone.

Comment: My apologies, I described it wrong in that comment. The question is asking how to avoid re-implementing the *handling of arguments* in the initialiser. Yes, the `parse_init` is non-standard, which is the problem raised in the question :-)