# In Cython class, what's the difference of using __init__ and __cinit__?

Tags: python, class, oop, cython

Code block 1 using `__init__`

```
%%cython -3
cdef class c:
    cdef:
        int a
        str s
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=1
        self.s="abc"
    def get_vals(self):
        return self.a,self.s
m=c()
print(m.get_vals())
```

Code block 2 using `__cinit__`

```
%%cython -3
cdef class c:
    cdef:
        int a
        str s
    def __cinit__(self):  # cinit here
        self.a=1
        self.s="abc"
    def get_vals(self):
        return self.a,self.s
m=c()
print(m.get_vals())
```

1. I tested both of these codes, and both run without error.
   In this case, what's the point of using `__cinit__` instead of `__init__`?
2. I've read the official article, I got confused by one sentence:

   > If you need to pass a modified argument list to the base type, you will have to do the relevant part of the initialization in the `__init__()` method instead, where the normal rules for calling inherited methods apply.

What does "modified argument" mean? Here, why should I use init rather than cinit?

Comment: Check this discussion on [cython-users group](https://groups.google.com/g/cython-users/c/BmPhFsYRIhM)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's mainly about inheritance. Suppose I inherit from your class `C`:

```
class D(C):
    def __init__(self):
        pass  # oops forgot to call C.__init__

class E(C):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        super().__init__(self)  # called it twice
```

How `__init__` ends up being called is entirely up to the classes that inherit from it. Bear in mind there may be multiple layers of inheritance.

Additionally, [a fairly common pattern for creating classes that wrap C/C++ objects is to create a `staticmethod` `cdef` function as an alternative constructor](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#existing-pointers-instantiation):

```
cdef class C:
    def __cinit__(self):
        print("In __cinit__")

    @staticmethod
    cdef make_from_ptr(void* x):
        val = C.__new__(C)
        # do something with pointer
        return val
```

In this case again, `__init__` typically isn't called.

In contrast `__cinit__` is guaranteed to be called exactly once and this happens automatically by Cython at an early stage of the process. This is most important when you have `cdef` attributes (such as C pointers) that your class relies on being initialized. It would be impossible for a Python derived class to even set these up, but `__cinit__` can ensure that they are.

In your case it probably doesn't matter - use whichever you're happy with.

---

In terms of "modified arguments" it's saying you can't replicate this with `__cinit__`:

```
class NameValue:
     def __init__(self, name, value):
         self.name = name
         self.value = value

class NamedHelloPlus1(NamedValue):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__("Hello", value+1)
```

i.e. `NamedHelloPlus1` controls what arguments `NamedValue` gets. With `__cinit__` Cython all the calls to `__cinit__` receive exactly the same arguments (because Cython arranges the call - you cannot call it manually).

Answer (score 3):

1. **cinit** should be used where C level initialization of object is required. Please be careful here, they may not be a fully valid python object yet. However, anything that cannot be done in **cinit**, needs to happen in **init**. By this time, all objects are valid python objects.
2. if I understand it correctly, it points to modifiable arguments in derived class. Arguments list may be modified or parsed differently that the base type **init**. In such cases init needs to be used. [This may be useful in giving you an insight on what I am trying to explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39887422/more-arguments-in-derived-class-init-than-base-class-init)