# what's the meaning of the asterisk sign in argument list of asyncio.run(coro, *, debug=False) of new Python coroutine feature?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, coroutine

I know the *tuple_arguments and **dict_arguments when defining a function. But it's my first time to see a single * in arguments list of a function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a syntax error. What is the exact version of Python you are using? Does the code actually run?

Comment: The single * is allowed in a function definition, but not a function call.

Comment: the single * is frequently used in `asyncio`, standard coroutine library of Python 3.7.`def run(main, *, debug=False):`, `async def wait(fs, *, loop=None, timeout=None, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED):`.

Comment: Found the answer in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298976/8831771)