# How can I make mandatory to name required arguments of a function when the function is invoked, without giving the arguments a default value?

Tags: python, function, arguments, named

In Python, is it possible to make mandatory to name required arguments of a function when the function is invoked, without giving the arguments a default value?

for example:

```
def return_apparence(eyes_color, shirt_color):
    print("my eyes are %s.\n" % eyes_color)
    print("my shirt is %s." % shirt_color)
```

I would like to re-write this function **without giving its arguments a default value** and so that when it is invoked, arguments must be named with specific keywords (such as `eyes_color`, `shirt_color`)? like this:

```
return_apparence(eyes_color="blue", shirt_color="red")
```

> my eyes are blue 
> my shirt is red

How can I do it?

### Why I am asking this

This because I would like to avoid the function to be called by mistake with inverted arguments, like this:

```
def return_apparence(eyes_color, shirt_color):
    print("my eyes are %s.\n" % eyes_color)
    print("my shirt is %s." % shirt_color)

return_apparence("red", "blue")
```

> my eyes are red ---- (this can't be)
> my shirt is blue

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think that's possible. 

To avoid the confusion I think you should just write proper documentation for your function (with examples if necessary) and clearly understood argument names (with type hints, if necessary).

Comment: I confirm this question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965271/forced-naming-of-parameters-in-python (my bad!), and in my case, the solution is to put the bare asterisk at the beginning of the arguments tuple, like so: `def return_apparence(*, eyes_color, shirt_color):` , so that the developer is forced to name `eyes_color` and  `shirt_color` when invoking the function