# Python Decorator to force passing arguments explicitly

Tags: python, function, arguments, python-decorators

I have a function that can receive 3 arguments. Only `X` is mandatory and I could write this function like

```py
def foo(X, A=None, B=None):
    pass
```

But I want to force the user to call this function passing explicitly the arguments

```py
foo(X=1, A=2, B=3)
foo(1, 2, 3)  # Error
```

Is it possible make a decorator for that?

```py
@explicitarguments
def foo(X, A=None, B=None):
    pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can modify the function definition, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965271/forced-naming-of-parameters-in-python) question.

A minimal decorator to patch existing functions looks like this:

```
def explicitarguments(f):
    def f_new(**kwargs):
        return f(**kwargs)        
    return f_new
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a decorator that raise and error when *args* are passed as input.

In this way you can even raise a specific error in case you need to catch this kind of error in a potential try/expect framework.

```
def explicitarguments(func):
    '''Simple decorator to enforce user to use only keyword'''

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if args:
            raise RuntimeError('You can not pass arguments without keyword')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```