# What does *(asterisk) mean in python docs?

Tags: python

This is what the python docs(https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) says:

```
min(iterable, *[, key, default])
```

But the other fuctions are like this:

```
iter(object[, sentinel])
pow(base, exp[, mod])
getattr(object, name[, default])
```

Only max/min has * in its definition.
But for what?
What's the difference between the upper one and the below one?

```
min(iterable[, key, default])
```

Comment: This should answer your question I guess. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298976/9848043

Comment: Both answers answers part of the  question but not all of it.

Answer (score 2):

### Difference and meaning

> TL;DR: * enforces keywords, key=value, arguments passing.

```py
min(iterable, *[, key, default])
```

You can read above as `min` takes iterable as `required` and first argument, and key and default as `optional arguments`, meaning you don’t have to pass them, that needs to be passed as `key=value` pairs. The * forces you to do that. So you cannot pass `key` or `default` without clearly stating that it is key or default or both you wish to pass. E.g. `min([1,2,3])`, `min({'a','b'}, key=somekey)`

```py
min(iterable, key, default)
```

Here we mean `min` takes iterable, key, and default as `required arguments`. The position of the argument matters as the first is iterable, second key and third default unless you pass them as key=words arguments e.g `min(default=somedefault, iterable=(1,2,3), key=somekey)`,`min([1, 3], default=x, key=y)`.  But all three arguments must be passed. As you can see the second can be messy while the first is cleaner.