# Argument convention in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, coding-style, conventions

I am new to PyTorch and while going through the examples, I noticed that sometimes functions have a different convention when accepting arguments. For example `transforms.Compose` receives a list as its argument:

```py
transform=transforms.Compose([  # Here we pass a list of elements
   transforms.ToTensor(), 
   transforms.Normalize(
      (0.4915, 0.4823, 0.4468), 
      (0.2470, 0.2435, 0.2616)
   )
]))
```

At the same time, other functions receive the arguments individually (i.e. not in a list). For example `torch.nn.Sequential`:

```py
torch.nn.Sequential(  # Here we pass individual elements
    torch.nn.Linear(1, 4),
    torch.nn.Tanh(),
    torch.nn.Linear(4, 1)
)
```

This has been a common typing mistake for me while learning.

I wonder if we are implying something when:

- the arguments are passed as a list
- the arguments are passed as individual items

Or is it simply the preference of the contributing author and should be memorized as is?

**Update 1:** Note that I do not claim that either format is better. I am merely complaining about lack of consistency. Of course (as Ivan stated in his answer) it makes perfect sense to follow one format if there is a good reason for it (e.g. `transforms.Normalize`). But if there is not, then I would vote for consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a convention, it is a design decision.

Yes, [`torch.nn.Sequential`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sequential.html) ([*source*](https://torch%20%3E%20torch.nn.modules.container)) receives individual items, whereas [`torchvision.transforms.Compose`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.Compose.html#torchvision.transforms.Compose) ([*source*](https://TORCHVISION.TRANSFORMS.TRANSFORMS)) receives a single *list* of items. Those are arbitrary design choices. I believe PyTorch and Torchvision are maintained by different groups of people, which might explain the difference. One could argue it is more coherent to have the inputs passed as a list since it is as a varied length, this is the approach used in more conventional programming languages such as C++ and Java. On the other hand you could argue it is more readable to pass them as a sequence of separate arguments instead, which what languages such as Python.

In this particular case we would have

```
>>> fn1([element_a, element_b, element_c]) # single list
```

vs

```
>>> fn2(element_a, element_b, element_c) # separate args
```

Which would have an implementation that resembles:

```
def fn1(elements):
    pass
```

vs using the [star argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965271/forced-naming-of-parameters-in-python/14298976#14298976):

```
def fn2(*elements):
    pass
```

---

However it is not always up to design decision, sometimes the implementation is clear to take. For instance, it would be much preferred to go the *list* approach when the function has other arguments (whether they are positional or keyword arguments). In this case it makes more sense to implement it as `fn1` instead of `fn2`. Here I'm giving second example with keyword arguments. Look a the difference in interface for the first set of arguments in both scenarios:

```
>>> fn1([elemen_a, element_b], option_1=True, option_2=True) # list
```

vs

```
>>> fn2(element_a, element_b, option_1=True, option_2=True) # separate
```

Which would have a function header which looks something like:

```
def fn1(elements, option_1=False, option_2=False)
   pass
```

While the other would be using a [star argument](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) under the hood:

```
def fn2(*elements, option_1=False, option_2=False)
   pass
```

*If an argument is positioned after the star argument it essentially forces the user to use it as a keyword argument...*

Mentioning this you can check out the source code for both `Compose` and `Sequential` and you will notice how both only expect a list of elements and no additional arguments afterwards. So in this scenario, it might have been preferred to go with `Sequential`'s approach using the star argument... but this is just personal preference!

Comment: Thanks Ivan! I agree that the 'design is chosen by the developers' and would be happy to follow whatever the developers have chosen. But my question is exactly what you have stated: 'sometimes it is more relevant to pass information grouped as a list'. What did the developers have seen in `torch.nn.Sequential` that made them thinking: "it should be separate", same for `transforms.Compose` the other way around. To me, both functions could follow one format or the other, as long as we stay consistent.

Comment: Yes, `torch.nn.Sequential` receives individual items, whereas `torchvision.transforms.Compose` receives a list. Those are arbitrary design choices, I'm afraid there is nothing to add there! But indeed, I missed your example since I took Normalize to illustrate my point, while you were referring to Compose vs Sequential. It's a matter of preference. I believe PyTorch and Torchvision were not designed/maintained by the same people, which might explain the difference. I would  personally go for `Sequential`'s approach.

Comment: @Amin.A, sure I have edited my answer above with additional elements to it.