# Access OptimizeResult in scipy.optimize.minimize callback function

Tags: python, callback, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to define a callback function to be used when optimizing. I am only interested in the current objective function's value for each iteration.

The documentation suggests, that most optimize methods, and specifically BFGS (my method used), [support a callback function with the signature](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize): `callback(OptimizeResult: intermediate_result)`. But trying to access the intermediate_result's *fun* attribute throws AttributeError.

Using the signature `callback(xk)` works fine, accessing only the parameter of the current iteration. But to get the value of my objective at each iteration, I would need to re-evaluate the objective, which is not desirable.

How can I get the objective value at each iteration to be returned in my callback without redundant function evaluations of my objective?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) you linked closely it says:

> Note that the name of the parameter must be `intermediate_result` for the callback to be passed an `OptimizeResult`.

Meaning, you *cannot* leave the variable as `xk` and have it be a positional argument, it *must* be called `intermediate_result` and *must* be a keyword argument. In Python 3 you can force a function argument to be a keyword argument by putting `*` for the first argument ([relevant Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298976/12131013)).

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen

def callback(*, intermediate_result):
    print(intermediate_result.fun)

x0 = [1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2]
res = minimize(rosen, x0, method="Nelder-Mead", tol=1e-6, callback=callback)
```

Comment: Tried it on my code and your example as well, but get an ```TypeError: callback() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given```

Comment: That's from copying my code exactly?

Comment: Yes. It looks like it is still trying to resolve the positional argument, referring to the other signature, since when I look into the problematic scipy code in _optimize.py (line 1406-1407) the problematic if condition states: 
```
if callback is not None:
    callback(xk)
```

Comment: You can also try writing the function call as `callback(intermediate_result=None)` and see if it works. (By the way, it's just one tick on each side for inline code).

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists. `numpy.ndarray object has no attribute fun` (thx for the hint :) ) so looks like the callback is still taking the parameters as attributes, not the actual optimization object...

Comment: What version are you using?